# Why does this wildcarded function tells me it has the wrong number of parameters?

Tags: scala, wildcard, anonymous-function

The offending code was:

```
<console>:47: error: wrong number of parameters; expected = 2
            terms.foldLeft(r.unitA)(r.add(_, _.eval(x)))
```

I solved my problem by writing:

```
 terms.foldLeft(r.unitA)((a,b) => r.add(a, b.eval(x)))
```

But I'd still like to know what prevented my initial attempt?

Answer (score 2):

From what I've read on this type of issue, when you use "_" as a place holder for an anonymous parameter of a function, the scope of that function is the innermost parenthesis containing it.  So when you wrapped your two placeholders with `r.add()`, the scope of the params is lost.  Check out this link and see if it helps explain the rules better.

http://www.scala-lang.org/node/2916

Answer (score 2):

Here is the section of the SLS 6.23:

http://iainmcgin.github.io/scala-ref-markdown/#placeholder-syntax-for-anonymous-functions

Updated link:

http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#placeholder-syntax-for-anonymous-functions

Daniel Sobral's post says:

> "When you use "_" as a place holder for an anonymous parameter of a
>   function, the scope of that function is the innermost parenthesis
>   containing it. *Most of the time.*

Updated spin:  I think the syntax explanation from the spec is easier to get, that the placeholder doesn't escape an enclosing `Expr`.  There are various duplicate questions.