# Why does using underscore make this list comprehension only print one dot?

Tags: scala

In Scala 2.9.2

```
List(List(1,5,4),List(7,9,11)).flatten.map {i => println(i); identity(i) }.find { _ % 2 == 0 }
```

Prints:

```
1
5
4
7
9
11
Option[Int] = Some(4)
```

But

```
List(List(1,5,4),List(7,9,11)).flatten.map { println("."); identity(_) }.find { _ % 2 == 0 }
```

Prints

```
.
Option[Int] = Some(4)
```

I must admit, I'm slightly suprised by this behavior. Underscore does not seem to be merely a shorthand for the equivalent in-line function, but has other affects on the code. What is going on here?

Comment: Somewhat similar http://stackoverflow.com/a/19600953/1296806

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
{ println("."); identity(_) }
```

is not a function that prints a dot and returns identity. It's a code block that is executed once when the expression is evaluated, prints a single dot, then returns the function `identity(_)`, which in turn is mapped over the flattened list.

Comment: This explanation is not completely correct. `{ println("."); identity(_) }` contains a function, in fact it is desugared to `{ println("."); x => identity(x) }`. This means the identity function is called for all values of the list.

Comment: @sschaef I think maybe larsmans said that (the first time :). It is strange that blocks are not mysterious or abstract, but generate many questions and verbiage to answer them. It's not just underscore's fault.

Comment: @som-snytt ok, after reading his sentence again it makes more sense to me. EDIT: he has edited his answer, that is why it makes more sense now to me ;)