# Scala - Confusion with lambda in map function

Tags: scala, lambda

I am learning Scala and was experimenting in the command line. I am not able to understand why the second line fails to compile. Can someone please explain.

```
val list = List(1,2,3,4)
list.map(_+1)           //This works. List(2,3,4,5)
list.map(List(_+1))     //But, Compilation Fails here
list.map(x=>List(x+1))  //This works. List(List(2),List(3),List(4),List(5))
```

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7627156/334862

Comment: Take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/16502936/187261 it has reference to documentation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Scala will expand `_` (when used in a placeholder position) to `x => x`, except when such expansion would result in the identity function (more on that at the end of this answer):

```
list.map(_+1)       // same as list.map(x => x + 1)       (1)
list.map(List(_+1)) // same as list.map(List(x => x+1))   (2)
```

In the case of `(1)`, scala can infer that `x` has type `Int` (since `list: List[Int]`).
However `(2)` fails with

```
error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => x$1.$plus(1))
```

because scala can't infer `x`'s type in `List(x => x+1)`.

---

About the expansion and identity function:

```
scala> list.map(List(_))
res3: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1), List(2), List(3), List(4))
```

works, because the `list.map(List(x => x))` expansion is rejected, and the next possible one is `list.map(x => List(x))`, which gives `res3`.

Comment: Gah, beat me to it.

Comment: "Scala will expand `_` to `x => x`, except when such expansion would result in the identity function". Isn't something wrong with this statement? `x => x` is the identity function.

Comment: @VictorMoroz: Ah yes, I might have to rephrase this. What I mean is: expanding `f(_)` to `f(x => x)` would replace `_` with the identity function. Expanding `f(_ + 1)` with `f(x => x + 1)` doesn't.

Comment: My understanding is that `_` alone will never be replaced with the identity function, check this: `List(1).map(_)`. I'm not quite sure where it's declared in the language spec.

Answer (score 1):

The type of `list` is `List[Int]`. So, the argument to `list.map(...)` has to be a function from `Int` to something.

What it seems you are trying to create with `List(_+1)` is a list of functions from integers to integers that happen to have one element: the successor function.

It fails to compile because this is one of the cases where the Scala compiler is unable to infer the type of an expression. But actually, a `List[_]` *is* a valid function from `Int` to something:

```
val f = List(99, 88, 77)
f(1)                     // -> 88
```

So for your code to compile, you have to give the compiler a little hint so it typechecks:

```
val list = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
list.map(List[Function[Int, Int]](_ + 1))
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ type annotation
```

This is also valid:

```
list.map(List[Int => Int]](_ + 1))
```

It will compile but it'll fail at runtime, because you are trying to get elements 1, 2, 3 and 4 of a one-element list. If the list contained only zeros (the only valid index for that particular list) it'd work:

```
val list = List(0, 0, 0)
list.map(List[Function[Int, Int]](_ + 1))
// -> evaluates to a list of three functions
```

... or also if the list of functions contained enough elements for the index 1, 2, 3 and 4 to exist:

```
val list = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
list.map(List[Function[Int, Int]]( // a list of 5 functions:
  _ + 1,                           // 0) the successor function,
  _ * 10,                          // 1) the "append a zero" function,
  Math.abs,                        // 2) the absolute value function,
  _ / 2,                           // 3) the half function
  x => 2                           // 4) the constant function with value 2
))
// -> evaluates to a list of four functions. Can you guess which ones?
```

Comment: `list.map(List((_:Int) + 1)))` is arguably simpler than `list.map(List[Function[Int, Int]](_ + 1))`